# Tracking data change on Oracle 9 without timestamps or indexing

Tags: oracle, google-bigquery

We're building a data warehouse on BigQuery, which includes data from a old Oracle 9 transactional database (still active), which does not include any indexing or timestamps.

Using Standard SQL, I would like to analyse changes in some tables imported from this database.

Simplifying the situation, imagine we have a two versions of the same table `before` and `after` as follows:

```
with before as (
    select 
    'U123' as user, 'Gum' as product, '3' as quantity 
    union all 
    select 
    'U456', 'Tissue', '20'
    union all
    select
    'U123', 'Cream', '1'
    )
```

and

```
with after as (
    select 
    'U123' as user, 'Gum' as product, '3' as quantity 
    union all 
    select 
    'U456', 'Tissue', '20'
    union all
    select
    'U123', 'Cream', '3'
    union all
    select
    'U456', 'Tomato', '5'
    )
```

So that row 4 was added and row 3 modified.

What is the correct approach to compare data and locate changes given there is no indexing nor timestamps?

So the comparative method should output:

```
user | product | quantity
U123 | Cream   | 3
U456 | Tomato  | 5
```

I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Please add a comment if you -1 so I may improve the question thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user, product, IFNULL(a.quantity, 0) - IFNULL(b.quantity, 0) AS quantity
FROM after a
FULL OUTER JOIN before b
USING(user, product)
WHERE IFNULL(a.quantity, 0) != IFNULL(b.quantity, 0)
```

When applied to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH before AS (
  SELECT 'U123' AS user, 'Gum' AS product, 3 AS quantity UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U456', 'Tissue', 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U123', 'Cream', 1
), after AS (
  SELECT 'U123' AS user, 'Gum' AS product, 3 AS quantity UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U456', 'Tissue', 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U123', 'Cream', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U456', 'Tomato', 5
)
SELECT user, product, IFNULL(a.quantity, 0) - IFNULL(b.quantity, 0) AS quantity
FROM after a
FULL OUTER JOIN before b
USING(user, product)
WHERE IFNULL(a.quantity, 0) != IFNULL(b.quantity, 0)
```

output is

```
Row user    product quantity     
1   U123    Cream   2    
2   U456    Tomato  5
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Great answers as usual. I’ve seen but had no time to try this out. I’ll do that soon and get back to this thread for feedback / accepting answer as required.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 9 keeps track of data change at Row level with the help of SCN (System Change Number). As a result any change performed through DML (INSERT/UPDATE) is internally captured with a TIMESTAMP.

How it works?

1. Create a Table with ROWDEPENDENCIES Option
2. Use SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) Function to get the TIMETAMP of Row Changes

Example:

```
-- Create Table
CREATE TABLE SCNTEST(USER NUMBER, PRODUCT NUMBER, QUANTITY NUMBER) ROWDEPENDENCIES;

-- Insert Data
INSERT ...
    
-- Query Data
SELECT USER, PRODUCT, QUANTITY, SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) FROM SCNTEST;
```

You can group data on `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)` value to get before and after records.

Comment: That’s great to know! However, in my use case it’s not applicable as we are not able to modify the software that uses the database. We’re only able to get data and store it in a data warehouse—until we’ll rid ourselves of the old software and bring in a new one.

Comment: I tried the `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)`  on existing tables of our system, and got `ORA-00904: "SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"` Does that mean the `ROWDEPENDENCIES` was not activated? Or should the syntax perhaps be different?

Comment: Yes, you need to enable row level dependency tracking by using `ROWDEPENDENCIES` keyword

Comment: Can it be done after the table is created? (Edit: seems it cannot be done in `ALTER` clause see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58327/oracle-how-can-i-add-rowdependencies-to-an-existing-table)

Comment: No, you need to recreate the table.